# Check if POST data is set, can't get it working

Tags: php

I want to use PHP to check if $_POST["pass"] is set, and do something if it's not, and do something else if it is.... But I can't get it working, I'm sure my logic is wrong.

I have a php code that looks something like this...

```
if (!isset($_POST["pass"])) {
   ...some form with an input type text here...

   if (...wrote the wrong thing in input type text...) {
       echo "something is wrong....";
   }
   else {
    $pass_var = "Pass";
    $pass_var = $_POST["pass"];
   }
}
else {
echo "This thing is working...";
}
```

If I type the right thing in my input type text, I wan't to get to "This thing is working", and if not I wan't to echo "something is wrong....".

It works almost fine, except that if I type the right thing in my form, I never get to "This thing is working...".

The page just does nothing..

I'm sure it's the

```
$pass_var = "Pass";
$pass_var = $_POST["pass"];
```

that I'm doing wrong.

I know that I could set this up in another way to make it work, but I have a large script that is set up like this, and I really want it to work...

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>"` at the beginning of your script to see what's actually in `$_POST`.

Comment: You should check if it is set "first", and not the other way around. Try `if (isset($_POST["pass"])) { // do something } else { // do something else }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why "should" he do that? Purely preference.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart For me, it's only logical to check if a condition is first met and less confusing than starting at the end, as it were.

Comment: I agree with Jonathon Reinhart, it's simply preference.

Comment: The logic here is all wrong. The way the conditions are setup, this `if (!isset($_POST["pass"])) {` is working in conjunction with `else { 
echo "This thing is working...";` - [Consult the manual if/else](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) - [and IF structure here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php)

Comment: If you wrote a simplified program that actually shows the failure, it would be easier to debug. What you have shown is only "something like" the real code that is not working. And it is only pseudo-code. Your best bet is to add debug print statements as Jonathon Reinhart suggested above.

Comment: *"I want to use PHP to check **if** $_POST["pass"] **is set**"* <= and you're using `if (!isset($_POST["pass"]))` - this function is the total reverse of what you wrote. So again, if you want to check if something **"IS SET"** then use `if(isset` and not the `!` character that checks if it is **"NOT SET"**

Comment: OP logic appears to be incorrect with or without the "!". A better logic layout is presented by Jelle Ferwerda in his answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You test in the form against the $_POST NOT being set (See the !). You want however the post to be set!

```
if(isset($_POST["pass"])) 
  {
  print_r($_POST); // basic debugging -> Test the post array
  echo "The form was submitted";

  // ...some form with an input type text here...
  if(...wrote the wrong thing in input type text...) 
    {
    echo "something is wrong with the input....";
    }
  else 
    {
    // Valid user input, process form
    echo "Valid input byy the user";
    $pass_var = "Pass";
    $pass_var = $_POST["pass"];
    }
  }
else 
  {
  echo "The form was not submitted...";
  }
```

Comment: I'm going to upvote this. Some probably won't agree with me, but your logic is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `empty()` function of php

```
if(!empty($_POST['pass'])){
// do something
}else{
// do something else
}
```

Hope this will work for you .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "method='POST'" in your html form else $_POST isn't accessible in php, and logic was a bit screwy, try this?

e.g.

```
if (!isset($_POST["pass"])) {
    //no POST so echo form 
    echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='txtInput' />
    <input type='submit' name='pass' />
    </form>";
} elseif (isset($_POST["pass"])) {
    //have POST check txtInput for "right thing"
    if ($_POST["txtInput"] == "wrong thing") {
       echo "something is wrong....";
   } elseif ($_POST["txtInput"] == "right thing") {
    //$pass_var = "Pass"; 
    $pass_var = $_POST["pass"];
    echo "This thing is working...";
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, `if (!isset($_POST["pass"]))` means if `$_POST["pass"]` is **not** set, so you might want to remove the '!' which stands for not.

Comment: Clearly the OP knows that, because in the `else` case he says `"This thing is working..."`

Comment: @TheOnly92 That is intentional, `if (!isset($_POST["pass"])) {
   ...some form with an input type text here...
`

Comment: Well checked again and he says that the script ends up doing the *opposite* thing, so I think that's the reason.

Comment: Agreed. He does not realize the working of ! The script indicates he expects input in the $_POST array even though he is checkking for not existing of a form field.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I kind of beg to differ. *Just because when someone pops open the gas cap and it smells like gas, doesn't mean the gas tank is full.* ;-)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky The OP's logic is completely wrong. [See my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397156/check-if-post-data-is-set-cant-get-it-working#comment28751143_19397156) and read the question again, along with posted pseudo code. It doesn't make sense whatsoever.